# Make sql delete button to submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this function:

```
function delete_id(id)
{
    if(confirm('Sure To Remove This Record ?'))
    {
        window.location.href='?delete_id='+id;
    }
}
```

And this button in a table html table (generated from mysql) :

```
<td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id(<?php echo $rowdetails["ID"]; ?>)"><img src="images/b_drop.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>
```

Right now the button uses a delete query to delete rows from a database but Is it possible to make this button also submit this form and keep deleting rows like before :

```
<form name="statuschange" action="changestatus.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="<?php echo $rowdetails["InvoiceDetailID"]; ?>">
</form>
```

I also tried but it doesn't work :

```
function delete_id(id)
    {
        if(confirm('Sure To Remove This Record ?'))
        {
            window.location.href='?delete_id='+id;
            document.statuschange.submit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to make an AJAX call such that the deletion occurs without a page reload.  Is this correct? If so, have you made an attempt at writing the AJAX code? Are you using any particular javascript framework?

Comment: The delete button works fine, I want this button to delete the sql row then submit the form. If I use the code I posted then the forms submits but the button does not delete rows anymore

Answer (score 1):

Please use this to submit form

If you use form id

```
<form name="statuschange" id="statuschange" action="changestatus.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $rowdetails["ID"]; ?>"  />
```

then use it like this:

```
document.statuschange.submit();
```

Now form will be submitted and you will get ID to delete the record on the action page 'changestatus.php'.

Now perform delete query at this page. 'changestatus.php'

Comment: It does submit the form but it does not delete sql rows anymore.

Comment: You have to use window.location.href='?delete_id='+id; too.

Comment: I have modified the answer.

Comment: I did but it submits the form without deleting the row.

Comment: Yes the pages are in php, I'm new to java so I can't really figure out by myself how to write this function.

Comment: I think I rushed with the conclusion a little bit , I just found out that in fact the `<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $rowdetails["ID"]; ?>"  />` posts only the first ID of the table, it does not matter if I select the delete button on the third row or forth it still deletes only the first row. probably because `window.location.href='?delete_id='+id;` doesn't post the id to the changestatus.php. Please help.

Comment: What is your requirement now?

Answer (score 0):

You write correct. I think problem in php code. Look your html result source. Source must be like in this form:

```
<td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id(some_id)"><img src="images/b_drop.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>
```

Comment: The delete button works fine, I want this button to delete the sql row then submit the form.

Comment: Write the same function on form sumbit event (OnSubmit = "delete_id(<?php echo $rowdetails["ID"]; ?>)")t

Comment: Can you give a little more details please. Should I turn the `<a href..>` button in a `<input type="submit" OnSubmit = "delete_id(<?php echo $rowdetails["ID"]; ?>)">` button?

Comment: <form action="changestatus.php">
<input type="submit" value="delete_row" onClick="javascript:delete_id(123);" />
</form>

Comment: It does submit the form but it does not delete the row anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are a little confuse with what your doing.

```
window.location.href='?delete_id='+id;
```

Above line will recall tha page sending the parameter delete_id as GET method ($_REQUEST["delete_id"] to fetch it in PHP)

```
document.statuschange.submit();
```

Above line will call tha page sending the parameter delete_id as POST method ($_POST["delete_id"] to fetch it in PHP)

So you are asking to submit a form after leving the page (window.location.href made that happen). But you you only need to take away the

```
window.location.href line,
```

call

```
document.statuschange.submit();
```

as already doing, and fetch the delete_id with $_POST["delete_id"] and not $_REQUEST["delete_id"].

That will send the form and all other contents.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with ajax function

```
<script language="Javascript">
function delete_id(script_dir, id)
{
    if(confirm('Sure To Remove This Record ?')) {
        var result = "";

        try {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4){
                if (req.status==200) {
                    alert('Row deleted');
                    document.statuschange.submit();
                }
            }       
        }
        req.open("GET", script_dir + '?delete_id='+id, true);
        req.send(null);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>


<form action="changestatus.php" method="post"> 
</form>

<button onClick="javascript:return delete_id('script_directory', 123);">delete_row</button>
```